# Stack Exchange account picture policy

Tags: discussion, profile-picture, policy

I have just realised that the picture I chose for my account has been changed back to the original and not by me.

Has anyone else experienced this? The picture wasn't offensive or anything, so I am wondering what is the platform policy on accounts' pictures.

Can anyone enlighten me please?

Comment: If it really was harmless, do you have a copy of the image to show us?

Comment: I can't find the exact one, but it was an optical illusion very similar to [this one](http://creativegreed.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Mind-Boggling-Optical-Illusions-10-590x590.jpeg).

Comment: If this is your Stack Overflow account you switched the image back to the identicon in July. This is the image - http://i.stack.imgur.com/531pc.jpg - if you want it.

Comment: Did I? Sorry about that! Well still Laura's answer is still informative.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Our policy is what you'd expect – the only time we'll change your profile image is if it's offensive, or if you're intentionally impersonating someone else (often, this is the result of a flag raised by another user alerting us to the offensive image).

That's not what happened here, though. It seems that at some point you had two accounts, and they were automatically merged by our system. Your merged account kept the generic identicon rather than your custom picture. You're free to change it back to your old one if you'd like.